# Form Group - Select drop down not populating, yet array shows in console

Tags: angularjs, angular

I've got a drop down within my form that for one reason or another just one populate with the data binding its been assigned. The data is coming through - I can output it to the console, but it just wont populate the select field.

The data is being provided by the loadOrganizations method, and the array outputs to my console when logged as seen here:

[image]

Any ideas on that I'm missing?  I have re written this a dozen times over and 16 different ways to no avail.

register.component.ts

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../_services/auth.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../../_services/alertify.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Clients } from '../../_models/clients';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Organizations } from '../../_models/organizations';
import { OrganizationService } from '../../_services/Organization.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'register.component.html',
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() cancelRegister = new EventEmitter();
  client: Clients;
  organizations: Organizations;
  registerClientForm: FormGroup;
  registerOrgForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private alertify: AlertifyService,
    private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private orgService: OrganizationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadOrganizations();
    this.createClientForm();
    this.createOrganizaionForm();
  }

  createClientForm() {
    this.registerClientForm = this.fb.group({
      FirstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      LastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      organization: new FormControl(),
      PhoneNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      ActiveDate: new FormControl(),
      EndDate: new FormControl(),
    });
  }

  loadOrganizations() {
    this.orgService.getOrganizations().subscribe((organizations: Organizations[]) => {
      organizations = organizations;
      console.log(organizations);
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  registerClient() {
    if (this.registerClientForm.valid) {
      this.client = Object.assign({}, this.registerClientForm.value);
      this.authService.register(this.client).subscribe(() => {
        this.alertify.success('Registration created successfully');
        this.router.navigate(['/manage/clients']);
      }, error => {
        this.alertify.error(error);
      });
    }
  }

  createOrganizaionForm() {
    this.registerOrgForm = this.fb.group({
      OrganizationName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      FirstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      LastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      PhoneNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      StreetAddress: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      City: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      State: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Country: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      PostalCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }

  registerOrganization() {
    if (this.registerOrgForm.valid) {
      this.organizations = Object.assign({}, this.registerOrgForm.value);
      this.orgService.CreateOrganization(this.organizations).subscribe(() => {
        this.alertify.success('Organization created successfully');
        // this.router.navigate(['/manage/clients']);
      }, error => {
        this.alertify.error(error);
      });
    }
  }

  cancel() {
    this.cancelRegister.emit(false);
    console.log('cancelled');
  }
}
```

full register.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card card-user">
      <tabset>
        <!-- BEGIN ORGANIZATION TAB -->
        <tab heading="Organization">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="card-title">Register New Client</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form
              [formGroup]="registerOrgForm"
              (ngSubmit)="registerOrganization()"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
            >
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Organization</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerOrgForm.get('OrganizationName').errors &&
                          registerOrgForm.get('OrganizationName').touched
                      }"
                      class="form-control"
                      formControlName="OrganizationName"
                      placeholder="Complete Security Ltd."
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter the organization name
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contact First Name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerOrgForm.get('FirstName').errors &&
                          registerOrgForm.get('FirstName').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="FirstName"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="John"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter a contact first name
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="text">Contact Last Name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerOrgForm.get('LastName').errors &&
                          registerOrgForm.get('LastName').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="LastName"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Smith"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter a contact last name
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerOrgForm.get('PhoneNumber').errors &&
                          registerOrgForm.get('PhoneNumber').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="PhoneNumber"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="604-929-3929"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter a phone number
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Street Address</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerOrgForm.get('StreetAddress').errors &&
                          registerOrgForm.get('StreetAddress').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="StreetAddress"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="123 Main St"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter a street address
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerOrgForm.get('City').errors &&
                          registerOrgForm.get('City').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="City"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="North Vanouver"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a city</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>State</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerOrgForm.get('State').errors &&
                          registerOrgForm.get('State').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="State"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="BC"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a state</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerOrgForm.get('Country').errors &&
                          registerOrgForm.get('Country').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="Country"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Canada"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a country</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Postal Code</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerOrgForm.get('PostalCode').errors &&
                          registerOrgForm.get('PostalCode').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="PostalCode"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="V7H 1S6"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter a postal code
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                  <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit
                </button>
                <button
                  type="reset"
                  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                  (click)="cancel()"
                >
                  <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Cancel
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </tab>
        <!-- END ORGANIZATION TAB -->
        <!-- BGIN CLIENT TAB -->
        <tab heading="Client">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="card-title">Register New Client</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form
              [formGroup]="registerClientForm"
              (ngSubmit)="registerClient()"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
            >
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contact First Name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerClientForm.get('FirstName').errors &&
                          registerClientForm.get('FirstName').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="FirstName"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="John"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter a contact first name
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="text">Contact Last Name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerClientForm.get('LastName').errors &&
                          registerClientForm.get('LastName').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="LastName"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Smith"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter a contact last name
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Organization</label>
                    <select
                      id="OrganizationName"
                      class="form-control"
                      formControlName="organization">
                      <option
                        *ngFor="let organization of organizations"
                        [value]="organization.id">
                        {{ organization.organizationName }}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please select the organization this user will belong to
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerClientForm.get('PhoneNumber').errors &&
                          registerClientForm.get('PhoneNumber').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="PhoneNumber"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="604-929-3929"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter a phone number
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email Address (Username)</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerClientForm.get('Username').errors &&
                          registerClientForm.get('Username').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="Username"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="user@email.com"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter the users email address
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Temporary Password</label>
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'is-invalid':
                          registerClientForm.get('Password').errors &&
                          registerClientForm.get('Password').touched
                      }"
                      formControlName="Password"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Password"
                      autocomplete="Create Password"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a password</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Start Date</label>
                    <input
                      formControlName="ActiveDate"
                      type="date"
                      class="form-control"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>End Date</label>
                    <input
                      formControlName="EndDate"
                      type="date"
                      class="form-control"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                  <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit
                </button>
                <button
                  type="reset"
                  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                  (click)="cancel()"
                >
                  <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Cancel
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </tab>
        <!-- END CLIENT TAB -->
      </tabset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

applicable section of register.componenet.html

```
<div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Organization</label>
                    <select
                      id="OrganizationName"
                      class="form-control"
                      formControlName="organization">
                      <option
                        *ngFor="let organization of organizations"
                        [value]="organization.id">
                        {{ organizations.organizationName }}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please select the organization this user will belong to
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: data in your console is showing 'i' icon means data is loaded very late use async-await on the function which is retrieving data

Comment: It's using a .NET API and the function is currently an async function on the API controller.  Is thee another area I should be looking at to make it an async method as well?

Comment: the method which is calling that api needs to be async-await

Comment: This would be my organization.service.ts

`getOrganizations(): Observable<Organizations[]> {
    return this.http.get<Organizations[]>(this.baseUrl + 'organizations', httpOptions);
  }`

I'm not certain how to make this method async (I'm learning Angular and am quite new at this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    You have an issue in following part:

    loadOrganizations() {
        this.orgService.getOrganizations().subscribe((organizations: Organizations[]) => {
          **organizations = organizations;**
          console.log(organizations);
        }, error => {
          this.alertify.error(error);
        });
      }

Declare first of all organizationsData: Organizations[]; Then, Instead of assigning in same variable try to use another variable like this.organizationsData = organizations;

Use this variable (organizationsData) in ngFor. That may fix your issue.
```

Comment: This is something I did think about earlier, but when doing so throws an error: 

Type 'Organizations[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Organizations': id, organizationName, FirstName, LastName, and 6 more.

Comment: Ok so this is getting somewhere.  In doing this, I need to bring in organization as an array `organizations: Organizations[];`.  This then populates the select drop down.  However, it now causes another issue with the registerOrganization function which throws the same error mentioned above with `this.organizations`

Comment: A dirty workaround was to declare organizations twice.  

`organizations: Organizations[];
  org: Organizations;`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

- `organizations: Organizations;` to `organizations: Organizations[];`
- `{{ organizations.organizationName }}` to `{{ organization.organizationName }}`

Try like this:

```
 <option *ngFor="let organization of organizations" [value]="organization.id">
    {{ organization.organizationName }}
 </option>
```

Comment: I get the same result - nothing populating the select options.

Comment: Why are you soing `this.organizations = Object.assign({}, this.registerOrgForm.value);`